# Expand Command Line Arguments Autohotkey

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

TLDR; I am trying to find an equivalent to bash `$@` in autohotkey

I am developing an autohotkey script which will run a specific program when triggered.

```
<^#i::Run D:\Scripts\myprog.exe "arg_1" "arg_2"
; Runs with whatever arguments I provide on pressing Ctrl + Win + I
```

I want the program to be started with specific command line arguments; that I provide during starting the script.

`> ahk_prog.exe arg_1 arg_2`

I basically want to be able to convert my command line arguments provided during starting the program to be able to run the Run Command every time I trigger it.

I tried this:

```
<^#i::Run D:\Scripts\myprog.exe %A_Args% ; A_Args is the array of CLI arguments 
; Runs with whatever arguments I provide on pressing Ctrl + Win + I
```

I also tried this(this one does not compile at all)

```
<^#i::Run D:\Scripts\myprog.exe "%*%" ; Trying Batch Like syntax since %1% and %2% are valid 
; Runs with whatever arguments I provide on pressing Ctrl + Win + I
```

Both of them do not work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A_Args`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Args)</sup> is an array, so you'll have join it into a string.
For example:

```
for each, arg in A_Args
    arg_list .= """" arg """ "

arg_list := RTrim(arg_list) ;trim trailing space (might be unnecessary)
MsgBox, % arg_list
```

Added quotes around the argument, since they will of course be needed if your argument has spaces in it.
Then you can add it to your `Run` command like so:

```
for each, arg in A_Args
    arg_list .= """" arg """ "

arg_list := RTrim(arg_list) ;trim trailing space (might be unnecesary)

<^#i::Run, % "D:\Scripts\myprog.exe " arg_list
```

---

Could also be done as a one-liner like so:

```
<^#i::Run, % "D:\Scripts\myprog.exe " RTrim(Format(StrReplace(Format("{:0" A_Args.length() "}", ""), 0, """{}"" "), A_Args*))
```